# How many revolutions per minute does a wheel make if its angular velocity is 20π radians per second?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Note: This is a homework question, however, I am not asking for anyone to do it for me.  I just need some direction in how I should go about solving it.**

The question reads:

> How many revolutions per minute does a wheel make if its angular velocity is 20π radians per second?

I am not familiar with angular velocity which is why I am lost as to where I should start to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Recall that $\pi$ radians is the same angle as $180$ degrees. So one revolution is $2\pi$ radians.

I expect no more help is needed. But you might want to leave your solution as a comment, so that I can tell you that you are right.

Comment: Based on your response, is the answer of 600 revolutions per minute correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks very much!  Also - what is the significance of the term "angular velocity" in the context of this question?

Comment: Angular velocity is a measure of how fast an object is turning.

Comment: Imagine the wheel is just rotating feely without changing position, like a ferris wheel. Velocity usually means how fast your displacement (where you are) is changing. Angular velocity means how fast an angle is changing. You can think of that angle as $\angle AOB$, where $A$ is a paint spot on the outside of the wheel, $O$ is the centre of the wheel, and $B is say a spot on the ground under the centre of the wheel. Angular velocity measures speed of rotation.